# Using for loops to shift an array of characters

Tags: java, for-loop, iteration

I have created a `char[]` that looks like

```
[A, A, B, C]
```

I want to remove the last character and then move up the others by one and store a new `char` at the first index. So it would look like this:

```
[D, A, A, B]
```

How would i do this using one or two `for loops`. I have the right idea I am just not implementing it correctly.

```
char[] array = new char[4]; //Array looks like [A, A, B, C]

for(int i = 0; i <= array.length - 2; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i + 1];
}
array[0] = 'D'; //This should be the new char at index 0.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It would make more sense to iterate from the end to the beginning of the array:

```
char[] array = new char[4]; //Array looks like [A, A, B, C]

for(int i = array.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    array[i] = array[i - 1];
}
array[0] = 'D';
```

Answer (score 2):

Using array for such a small size is ok.

Just to point out another approach, you can use [`LinkedList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList<Character>(Arrays.asList('A', 'A', 'B', 'C'));
System.out.println(list); // prints "[A, A, B, C]"
list.removeLast();
list.addFirst('D');
System.out.println(list); // prints "[D, A, A, B]"
```